# Why does this do-while statement print 20?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

This is a question I got wrong in a quiz. I believed it would print 5 since x is not lower than 4. Why does the do statement execute regardless of the while condition? Maybe I've been staring at this for too long. It currently prints 20.

```
int x = 5;
do{x*=4;} while(x<4);
System.out.print(x);
```

Comment: Because it's a `do ... while` loop, not a `while` loop. This is the only difference between those two kinds of loops: `do ... while` always executes the loop body at least once.

Answer (score 5):

A do-while loop always executes at least once. The loop condition is only checked after the first iteration ends.